# Websphere - httpRequest.getRemoteUser() returns NULL

Tags: websphere, httprequest

I'm using WAS 8.0 , and Virtual Member Manager as the authentication mechanism . The problem is that httpRequest.getRemoteUser is always returning null even though I logged in successfully.

I check if I successfully logged in by the default app of WAS called Snoop http://localhost:9083/snoop.

The detailed problem description and even an answer is given in the following [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014689667#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014689743) ;

I applied the given solution , meaning Application security' is enabled in WAS Console. But it is still returning NULL .   Any Idea why ?

**Web.xml :**

```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>RecordPersonaServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.persona.recordPersonaServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>RecordPersonaServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/persona/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Comment: You would need to add your `web.xml` to the question. The only reason could be that you are accessing unprotected page (and setting to make authentication data available on unprotected pages is not set) or using some custom login mechanism, which doesn't correctly set authentication data. I assume you restarted the server after enabling Application security.

Comment: Gas,  I edited my question based on your comment.  And yes, I'm using a custom login mechanism that is Virtual Member Manager (VMM).  I'm using the default application called Snoop (http://localhost:9083/snoop)  to test my authentication mechanism and it works , plus shows what  the remote user name is (ex: admin).    And yes to your last question.  The server has been restarted.

Comment: So your application doesn't have any security constraints (if this is your full web.xml), so it is not protected and thats why you are getting NULL. Look for some other questions how to define `<security-constraint>` element to protect your application.

Comment: Yes that's the full web.xml. I do not think it is regarding security constratints. Because when I deploy the app on Linux server it works as expected. Same project with the same web.xml .  However did not work locally.

Comment: Maybe PUMA API can help there? With WPS using that was working